# python store function result to file

Tags: python, file, save, store

I got a function (see below) that gets data from Google analytics to my computer.
I would like to store the result in a csv file but I dont know how. please help me out.
I can print the result on screen, but can't save it

```
def print_top_pages(service, site, start_date, end_date, max_results=10000):
    """Print out top X pages for a given site.s"""
    query = service.data().ga().get(
        ids=site,
        start_date=start,
        end_date=end,
        dimensions='ga:dimension20,ga:date',
        metrics='ga:sessions,ga:sessionDuration',
       # sort='-ga:pageviews',
        #filters='ga:hostname!=localhost',
        samplingLevel='HIGHER_PRECISION',
        max_results=max_results).execute()
    return print_data_table(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the return with this.

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
     out.write(print_data_table(query))
```

you should get the same printed output in a file named output.txt

Comment: that givs NameError: name 'query' is not defined

Comment: def print_top_pages(service, site, start_date, end_date, max_results=10000):
    """Print out top X pages for a given site.s"""
    query = service.data().ga().get(
        ids=site,
        start_date=start,
        end_date=end,
        dimensions='ga:dimension20,ga:date',
        metrics='ga:sessions,ga:sessionDuration',
       # sort='-ga:pageviews',
        #filters='ga:hostname!=localhost',
        samplingLevel='HIGHER_PRECISION',
        max_results=max_results).execute()
with open("output.txt", "w") as out:
     out.write(print_data_table(query))